# only getting one record on mysql data call (angular-slimphp)

Tags: php, angularjs, rest, slim

I am trying to use the slim php framework as a restful backend to an angular frontend.
I'm having problems fetching all records from my sql database.
I am using the following code in my controller:

```
    function refreshlistings() {
    Data.get('getAllListings').then(function(results) {
        $scope.lists = results;
        var tempdata;
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.lists.length; i++) {
            $scope.lists[i].data = decrypt($scope.lists[i].data);
        }

        if (!$scope.lists) {
            $scope.lists = [];
        }

    });
}
```

in my factory:

```
obj.get = function(q) {
        return $http.get(serviceBase + q).then(function(results) {
            return results.data;
        });
    };
```

And my slim API looks like this:

```
$app->get('/getAllListings', function(){
$db = new DbHandler();
$listings = array();
$listings = $db->getAllRecords("select * from LISTINGTABLE");
echoResponse(200, $listings);
});
```

in my DbHandler class:

```
public function getAllRecords($query) {
    $r = $this->conn->query($query) or die($this->conn->error.__LINE__);
    return $result = $r->fetch_assoc();    
}
```

I am only getting back one record from my SQL.

I tried:

```
public function getAllRecords($query) {
    $r = $this->conn->query($query) or die($this->conn->error.__LINE__);
    while ( $row = $r->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC) ) {
    $data[] = $row;
    }
    return $data[];    
}
```

In my DbHandler class, but that gives me an error.
Can anyone help me out? thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only request one row. If you use PDO you can do this:

`$q = $db->query("SELECT ... ");
$results = $q->fetchAll();`

If you use mysqli, then you must traverse the result set and assign rows to an array.

Also, I see in your code that you return $data[]. You should return $data.